# transform a dataframe by concatenating values associated with a unique id

Tags: pandas

First, I apologize for the terrible name of this question.

My problem is that I can't seem to transform this dataframe:

[image]

into this dataframe:

[image]

I have tried a lot of things:
stack, groupby, pivots, self joins (merge), wide -> long, etc. I'm stuck.

I feel like this shouldn't be so hard -- I must be missing something.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
df = [    {'name' : 'Andy', 'col1': 's'},
          {'name' : 'Andy', 'col1':   't'},
          {'name' : 'Andy', 'col1':  'u'},
          {'name' : 'Andy', 'col1':  'v'},
          {'name' : 'Bob', 'col1':  'a'},
          {'name' : 'Bob', 'col1':  'b'},
          {'name' : 'Carl', 'col1':  'howdy'},
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df[['name', 'col1']]
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby`

```
print(df)

    name    col1
0   Andy    s
1   Andy    t
2   Andy    u
3   Andy    v
4   Bob     a
5   Bob     b
6   Carl    howdy

df.groupby('name')['col1'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

# Output:
    name    col1
0   Andy    s t u v
1   Bob     a b
2   Carl    howdy
```

Comment: I swear at one point I had tried this...this looks too easy :) 
Thanks!

Comment: actually, could you do me a big favor? What does it do when you use `['col1']` after the group by? The documentation doesn't say anything about doing this...

Comment: It means that you are selecting the column `col1` from the groupby object `df.groupby('name')` and applying a function on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `sum`

```
(df.col1+' ').groupby(df.name).sum().str[:-1]
Out[259]: 
name
Andy    s t u v
Bob         a b
Carl      howdy
Name: col1, dtype: object
```